# Any AS3 Maps API still avaialable?

Tags: actionscript-3

I need an AS3 maps API for a school project (AIR Desktop APP). I wanted to use Google Maps API but, since it is deprecated, I can't obtain a key. Any other good maps API I could use? I just need basic function: search for a city, get coordinates, calculate distance and place elements (circles/lines) on the map to connect the cities.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sure, right now im not availible but tomorrow i will post my answer

Comment: Nevermind it was google!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont have to use as3, you could use the JS Google Maps API in Adobe Air. Also you could try http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/as3-flex-flash. I have personally have not used MapQuest but I read good reviews about it.

Comment: Sadly I have to use AS3. Not because the project involves it, but because I don't know JS. Also, I have part of the project already made and would save me time.

Comment: I ended up signing for a mapquest key. The API looks really good.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ModestMaps.

- [Library](https://github.com/migurski/modestmaps-as3).
- [Simple tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/interactive_maps.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [**flash.media.StageWebView**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html) object or classes from [**flash.html**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/html/package-detail.html) to display web content.  However, you will have to create the web content yourself using Google Maps API and JavaScript.